JS event listener on stacked elements
I have multiples elements stacked with absolute positionning in CSS, and need to listen to events of each elements stacked not only the one on the top. So using pointer-events:none on the top one is not possible for me because I would lose events it. I know it's possible if the elements are parent/child but can't find a way when they are not ancestors and just moved with CSS on top of each other.
Here is a simplified example listening to mousemove/click and 2 divs stacked. In the console you can see that when the mouse is over the white square (over) we don't have anymore the event from the black square (under). I need to catch them both. The aim is to be able to listen to many events from elements stacked like we could with ancestors.


const over = document.getElementById('over')
const under = document.getElementById('under')

over.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log("Mouse Div Over");
});
over.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log("Click Div Over");
});
under.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log("Mouse Div Under");
});
under.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log("Click Div Under");
});
#under {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="over"></div>
  <div id="under"></div>
</div>



Hope someone can help me on this one, maybe it's not possible or I have missed something obvious...

this one might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834705/how-to-capture-custom-events-from-sibling-in-js-is-it-even-possible

event.current target may be able to help.

Could you clarify the design requirements for handlng mousenter and mouseleave in your use case? These two events don't bubble, and entering and leaving an element completely covered by another of a higher order would not fire any events for entering or leaving the element with lower z-index.

@traktor, the aim is to have both divs from the example getting the event (mouseenter, mouseleave, click, etc). But I think this is just not possible, as you mention when an element is on top of the other with z-index, it stop all mouse events to pass through. I was hopping to be able to catch it from the one over and maybe manually dispatching the same event to the one under.

Check if you think "event delegation" may be of help - events that bubble generated by positioned elements within the same stacking context  should bubble up to the relatively positioned wrapper object (noting mousenter and mouseleave events do not bubble and may not be fired on some elements in the stack.

You want to add your event listener on a DOM node higher up in your tree, and use document.elementsFromPoint() to find the elements under the mouse when the event occurs.


const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (event.target.id !== 'wrapper') {
    const elementsUnderMouse = document.elementsFromPoint(event.x, event.y);
    const elementIds = elementsUnderMouse.map(({ id }) => id).join(', ');
    console.log(`elements: ${elementIds}`);
  }
});
#under {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

#over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 420px;
  position: relative;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="over"></div>
  <div id="under"></div>
</div>




Thanks for you reply, I edited my question to be more clear, my example with mousemove was just a simplified one, I need to listen to many events that are from stacked elements. So mousemove, mouseenter, click, CustomEvent, etc. Like we can with ancestors. I don't think your solution would work for click for example.
